# Getting Java 7 to run on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I downloaded the SDK from [the official oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html) and I picked the linux x86 compressed binaries (second item on the list).  I'm on Windows 7 with an i7, but trying to install on an Ubuntu 11.04 VM I have running inside VirtualBox.

I tried following [this tutorial](http://balajitheone.blogspot.com/2011/08/installing-oracle-sun-jdk-17-on-ubuntu.html), but it's not working.

```
java -version
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Then I try

```
ls -al /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/bin/ja*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo  5650 2011-06-27 04:02 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo 16074 2011-06-27 04:03 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/bin/java_vm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo 76665 2011-06-27 04:03 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/bin/javaws
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The only difference I can spot between what you're seeing and the instructions is that the bin folder in the instructions is inside a jre folder, I'm not sure if that's relevant or not.

Comment: That is a good point; but after going back and fixing it I'm still having trouble getting it going.  I've updated my answer with relevant details.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized now, since it seems like the problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was, in fact, using the wrong jdk.  I was using i586 when I should have been using x64 binaries.

Comment: Should I delete this question, or is this information useful enough that I should leave it?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Vbox... you need the binaries that match your Linux architecture, whichever it is.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Dave I'd say it might be worth leaving it, since the error message you got didn't really tell you the problem someone else might fall into the same trap.

Comment: @Dave - Just make sure to answer your question so people know it's been solved.